# Calling Text From Another Screen With ScreenManager

Tags: android, python, spinner, kivy

I have a code like this on kv. file:

```
<Entry>:
    spin: myspin
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        cols: 1
        Spinner:
            id: myspin
            text: 'Choose One'
            values: ['No1', 'No2', 'No3']
        Button:
            text: "Login"
<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: Entry.myspin.text
```

On the last line, I want that Button's text value is the same from Spinner's chosen value. But I couldn't do that with this. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you say another screen, do you mean in another activity?

If so, you could use the onCreate/onStart and onResume functions to set the value of the button.

If the activity that contains the spinner is calling the activity where you want to display the data, you can pass the information through using putExtra

If you want the application to 'remember' that the spinner value has been selected, you may need to store the information either in a database or shared preferences pending the activation of the activity displaying the data.